# without losing old fees payment in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i am creating a student management system, i have 3 tables, student, fees, student_fee, the fee table contains the amount of fees and the student_fee contains reference to student.studentid and fee.feeid, so that whenever a student paid their fees, the studentid, feeid and paid_date will be insert into the student_fee table. Fees can increase the next year, how can i still keep the old records of fees payment without losing and causing any problem to the account

Comment: Please rewrite this question and its title. It is not clear at all what is the problem you are facing and what is the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing an entire history table separately, just add a column into the student_fee_paid table for the amount of the payment... so you can still query from it directly for the entire history of a student and it will have the historical values all in one... ex:

```
Student  Fee_ID DatePaid    FeeAmount
X         1      1/1/2009   $25
X         1      1/1/2010   $25
X         1      1/1/2011   $30
X         1      1/1/2012   $35
```

Otherwise it will just grow to a larger task... If you have 30 different fees, and the fee schedule amount changes for some but not all, what then...  You can keep your "Fee" table to reflect whatever the "Current" fee amount is, but as soon as its paid, stamp that amount immediately.... if rates change mid-year, yet another trouble / history consideration... don't worry about the otherwise minimal amount of data storage this will increase.

Answer (score 1):

Create a history of fee payment table.  StudentID, FeeID, DatePaid, AmountPaid

or Effectively Date your Fee table.

Comment: Effectively Date your Fee table : Can you explain more... Please

Comment: Can you please explain more on how to set an effective date for the fees. i want to know which will be a better approach or any tutorial link on this

Comment: The way it works is you add an EffectiveDate column to Fee.  Whenever you change Fee, you never update the table, only insert a new record with a new fee amount and Effective Date.  Then if you want to see what the fee was at any given date then you just get the record with the highest Effective Date that is earlier than the date in question.  It has its uses but probably isn't the best one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the table `fees` and `student_fee` for archive purpose.

You can use the `SELECT INTO` command.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp